# Using Angular Js to submit form and show results in different page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search form which consists of drop down fields and for that drop down select box data is showing dynamically using angular js... now i want to submit this form and show the result in different page using angular js..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect your input data from the form in object using `ng-model`. For example:

```
<select id="one" ng-model="modelData.firstOption" ng-options="item for item in items1"></select>
<select id="two" ng-model="modelData.secondOption" ng-options="item for item in items2"></select>
<button id="searchButton" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.modelData = {};
$scope.search = function () {
    // if you use ngRoute, create URL with parameters. For example:
    if (modelData.firstOption && modelData.secondOption) {
        window.location.href = 'searchResult/' + modelData.firstOption + '/' + modelData.secondOption;
    }
}

// in your routing configuration you must have something like
$routeProvider.when('/searchResult/:firstOption/:secondOption', {
    // see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider for more info
}
```